# How to run my own event handling Javascript code on a site using element inspector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-inspector

I want to run my own event handling javascript code on a site. Such as:

```
$(".dropdown li").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function (e) {

    var elm = $('ul:first', this);
    var off = elm .offset();
    var l = off.left;
    var w = elm.width();
    var docH = $(".container").height();
    var docW = $(".container").width();

    var isEntirelyVisible = (l+ w <= docW);

    if ( ! isEntirelyVisible ) {
        $(this).addClass('edge');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('edge');
    }
});
```

Is there any way to do that using firebug or element inspector?

Comment: What does "run my own event handling" mean?  Are you saying you want to install an event handler on a site that you don't control?  If so, you can use tools like [GreaseMonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Greasemonkey) to insert your own scripts into an existing site (when it is run on your own computer) each time you go to that page.  You can insert one off event handlers in the debug console for any page in any of the browser debuggers.

Comment: _"Is there any way to do that using firebug or element inspector?"_ Tried ?

Comment: @jfriend00: yes , something like that. Such as I want to add a css class to an element on mouse hover.

Comment: Do you want to do this one time or do you want the code to be inserted every time you go to that page?

Comment: @guest271314: Yes, I tried using my inadequate knowledge and was unable to do that.

Comment: @jfriend00: to run at document.ready and work for each mouse hover

Comment: You did not answer my question.  Do this one time only for testing something out or do you need it to run automatically everytime your browser goes to that web page.  The solution is entirely different depending upon the answer.

Comment: Then just write your code in an editor, copy it to the clipboard and paste it in the debug console in any browser's debugger.  The console will execute the code and it will be active in that page until you reload the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just write your code in an editor, copy it to the clipboard and paste it in the debug console in any browser's debugger. The console will execute the code and it will be active in that page until you reload the page.